# Open link with target="_blank" as default in Lexical editor

Tags: hyperlink, lexicaljs

I am using AutoLinkNode and LinkNode from '@lexical/link'.

How can I set target="_blank" to be default on newly created links? Do I need to override the LinkNode class or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can always pass in pre-defined default attributes with `target` set to `_blank`. If that is not an option - overwrite class itself.

Comment: @Justinas thy for you response, can you quickly post a code example?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly add LinkAttributes to your AutoLinkNode, LinkNode

```
    const linkAttributes = {
        target: "_blank",
        rel: "noopener noreferrer",
    };
```

And simply add the linkAttributes,

```
      editor.dispatchCommand(TOGGLE_LINK_COMMAND, {
        url: "https://",
        ...linkAttributes,
      });
```

For more information,[Module: @lexical/link](https://lexical.dev/docs/api/modules/lexical_link#linkattributes)

Comment: Hey — could you give more information on this? How can I directly add LinkAttributes without redefining the entire node?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the AutoLinkNode and LinkNode, but the easiest solution is registering a node transform listener like this example that I prepared. Please see: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-faraday-7l9vqy?file=/src/plugins/AutoLinkPlugin.js

In short, that would be doing something like for the LinkNode:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";
import { LinkNode } from "@lexical/link";

export default function LinkNodePlugin() {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!editor) return;
    const removeNodeListener = editor.registerNodeTransform(
      LinkNode,
      (node) => {
        if (!node) return;

        const dom = editor.getElementByKey(node.__key);
        if (!dom) return;
        dom.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      }
    );
    return () => removeNodeListener();
  }, [editor]);
  return null;
}
```

And something like that for the AutoLinkNode:

```
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!editor) return;
    const removeNodeListener = editor.registerNodeTransform(
      AutoLinkNode,
      (node) => {
        if (!node) return;
        const dom = editor.getElementByKey(node.__key);
        if (!dom) return;
        dom.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      }
    );
    return () => removeNodeListener();
  }, [editor]);
```

Comment: Hope that helps you, @nerdess. Otherwise, let me know!